# How to scroll to a specifc element when there is already an # anchor on the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I have a web site on based on SkelJS that currently loads a different part of the webpage by appending an #anchor to the url like this:

[image]

Note that #blog loads the blog page, the scroll is at the top. Inside the Blog page I need to scroll to a certain article. **How can I use two anchors so that something like #blog#article_x would work? I suppose I have to look for a workaround since anchoring 2 ids makes no sense, is there a work around?**

Additional notes:

- Note that if a change #blog to #article_x it actually goes to the desired article however if someone shares the link it won't go to the article because it will look for #article_x on the homepage, where it does not exists.
- Here is a demo of the template I'm using (http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/astral/#) note how the #anchor loads the desired page.

Comment: Are all your blogs on the same page? Also if `someurl/?...#blog` goes to the blog then I believe the blog also must be part of the page at `someurl`. If all your blogs are also on the same page then `#article_x`should also work.

Comment: @aa333 I don't know what you mean with "blogs on the same page", there is only one blog page, inside the blog there are many articles, look at the following website http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/astral/#. Basically what I want is to scroll to an specific id given that an #anchor is already there used to change the pages.

Comment: All the pages on that link are basically on the same page i.e. part of the same html body, which is why `#anchor` works for work,contact etc. If you're going to put all your blogs in one html body, which is same as the homepage's body then `#article_x` will work, else you will have to provide another url.

Comment: @aa333 For some reason it does not works, for example the URL someurl/?lang=spa#article1 sends me to the homepage (to someurl/?lang=spa#home), but I feel that the answer is very close, I think it does not load the actual blog page because the div has the property "display: none", until the Blog button is pressed it becomes "display: block".

Comment: Well anything with `display` set to `none` will not be rendered at all. Which is why `#article_x` doesn't work for them. There are two ways you can fix this--either set `display` to anything but none or put all blog articles on a separate page and `href` with anchors to that page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hash that contains both page and element. Then split and then do your page load then scroll, i.e. `#blog,someelement`

```
//on page load or wherever you detect the hash
$(function(){
   var hash = window.location.hash;
   var ele = null;
   //Detect if there is a splitable hash 
   if(hash.indexOf(",") != -1){
      var parts = hash.split(",");
      hash = parts[0];
      ele = jQuery("#"+parts[1]);
   }
   //whatever function you do to load the blog page
   loadPage(hash,ele);
});

function loadPage(page,ele){
   //do page loading
   $("#page").load("http://someurl.com",function(){
      //if there was no second part to the hash 
      //this will be skipped
      if(ele){
         $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: ele.offset().top
         },1000);
      }
   });
}
```

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pevans02/D8dy3/)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the ID of the element that you want to scroll to is **myelement** you can use below jquery code to smoothly scroll to it.

```
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop : $("#myelement").offset().top},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can scroll to specific div when it has id or class

```
 var $id=window.location.href.split('#')[1];
 $('html, body').scrollTop($("#"+$id).offset().top)
```